# Can I record mpeg2 and play mpeg2 in BCB 6.0 by using Mitov VideoLab?

Tags: video, c++builder, video-processing, mpeg

I need to record a camera view into mpeg2 format, cause the default settings of "VLAVIPlayer" just give me uncompressed .avi file, which is extremely big (60 MB with just 10 sec...).

Also, I need to load in mpeg2 file and transfer it into a sequence of bitmaps so I can do some image processing stuff.

Or there is other tool that can do the above jobs under BCB 6.0?

Answer (score 0):

You should look here: [Support](http://www.mitov.com/support)

But it looks like you can get a frame by connecting 'something' to the output pin of the player.  If the class is not supplied by Mitov then you have to write a class that has an input pin to get the frame data.